# Record retention requirements for individuals in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, document-retention

I took a search through the site and read the FAQs and I really don't think this is off-topic here as it does have to do with personal finance. And I did find [this thread](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/what-should-i-do-with-my-paper-financial-documents), but I didn't see any official documentation.

Where would I find the schedule for required record retention for **individuals**? I've found the state statute requirements for agencies, the business schedules, but I can't seem to find the record retention guidelines for individuals (bank statements, filed taxes, receipts, etc). I'm looking to find some sort of *official documentation*. I'm located in the USA. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/what-should-i-do-with-my-paper-financial-documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an IRS [Publication 552](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p552/ar02.html#en_US_publink10008614) covering records retention

The publication covers many areas, including proof of income, bank statements, old tax returns. There is a table that talks about how long to keep the records. In general it is 3 to 6 years. But for property it is 3 to 6 years after you dispose of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the IRS publication references the 3-6 year time span. And no limit for fraud.

But. I get a notice that some stock I owned 10 years ago has a settlement pending, and the records of this stock purchase and sale would potentially get me back some money.

I get my Social Security statement (the one they stopped sending, but this was before then) and I see the 1995 income shows zero.

Both of these were easily resolved with my returns going all the way back, and my brokerage statement as well. For the brokerage, I recently started downloading all statements as PDFs, and storing a copy away from home. Less concerned about the bank statements as I've never had an issue where I'd need them.